# Why is the for of loop inside the functions body not giving me the expected output that the traditional for loop is doing?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, for-of-loop

Why is the for of loop inside the functions body not giving me the expected output that the traditional for loop is doing? Seems like the el in the for of loop is not the same as iterable[i] in the for loop?

```
var uniqueInOrder = function(iterable){
     let unique = [];
     for(let el of iterable){
         let cur = el;
         let next = el + 1;
         if(cur !== next){
             unique.push(cur)
         }
     }
     return unique;
}
uniqueInOrder('AAAABBBCCDAABBB')  // unexpected output

// Returns expected output
var uniqueInOrder = function(iterable){
     let unique = [];
     for(var i = 0; i < iterable.length; i++){
         let cur = iterable[i];
         let next = iterable[i + 1];
         if(cur !== next){
             unique.push(cur)
         }
     }
     return unique;
}
uniqueInOrder('AAAABBBCCDAABBB') // ----> ["A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "B"]
```

Comment: What is `el + 1` supposed to be ? `el` is not a pointer. You are comparing `'A'` to `'A'+1`

Comment: As a side note, the second loop should only iterate as far as `iterable.length - 1`.

Comment: You can't replicate the second function using a `for...of` loop because you need indexes and `for...of` doesn't give you any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @Sxribe describe, the for/of loop is fundamentally different, and you can't use `el+1` to get the next value.

A functionnal way to get the same result with both loops is :

```
var uniqueInOrder = function(iterable){
     let unique = [];
     let prev = ''
     for(let el of iterable){
         let cur = el;
         if(cur !== prev){
            prev = el
             unique.push(prev)
         }
     }
     return unique;
}
console.log(uniqueInOrder('AAAABBBCCDAABBB'))

// Returns expected output
var uniqueInOrder = function(iterable){
     let unique = [];
     for(var i = 0; i < iterable.length; i++){
         let cur = iterable[i];
         let next = iterable[i + 1];
         if(cur !== next){
             unique.push(cur)
         }
     }
     return unique;
}
console.log(uniqueInOrder('AAAABBBCCDAABBB'))
```

In this example instead of checking the current value against the next one, we check the current value against the previous one.

Answer (score 3):

Your issue is in your first function.

In JavaScript, `element` in `for (let element of inerable) {}` is not the same as `i` in your traditional `for` loop. When you write `let next = el +`, you are adding `1` to an element, not a number (so, in this case you are doing `'A' + 1`, like @Seblor said).

tl;dr `el` is not the same as `i`

Answer (score 0):

As @Sxribe is saying, you get the element instead of the `i` count.

So you need to check if `el` exits in the array and push it to the array if it dosen't.
So something like this would do it.

```js
function uniqueInOrder (iterable){
   let unique = [];
   for(let el of iterable){
      let cur = el;
      if(unique.indexOf(el) === -1){
         unique.push(cur)
      }
   }
   return unique;
}

console.log(uniqueInOrder('AAAABBBCCDAABBB'));
```